# Понижение z-index элементов внутри div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Структура:

```
<div class="accordion">
<div class = "card"></div>
<div class = "card"></div>
<div class = "card"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно уменьшать z-index каждого card на 1, у первого .card значение z-index должно быть 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion > .card");
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].style.zIndex = 20 - i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В классическом css нет перебора, такчто если количество элементов заранее неизвестно, или может поменятся, только с помощью js. Обходите все элементы и устанавливаете .style({z-index: m -1}), инициализируйте с let m = 21;